# how to get textbox value and put it in the URL?

Tags: url, web

[image]

I'm using javascript for my codes: I have this sample screenshot of my website, my problem is I don't know how to get the value (coordinates) of the text box and put it in the URL. I tried this code ' **window. location = window.location + '?loc=' + document.getElementById("latlng").value;** " and its adding the value in the URL but it keeps on refreshing/loading my page, what seems to be the problem? please help me. than you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `window.location` will force page to reload.

To change pin position on the map without full page reload you need to use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Comment: if you look into the image. I want to get the value (coordinates) of a textbox and add the value on the URL. can you help me?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I don't understand which result you expect to receive. Do you want to change pin position on the map?

Comment: yeah exactly! as I search for the coordinates it also display the location in the map. One more thing, when i change/put a coordinates in the address bar, it also display the location. just like google(google maps) locating coordinates.